# How to find % of which methods of a particular library are being used?

Tags: android, methods, code-coverage, static-code-analysis, gradle-plugin

I have several libraries in play, in many apps.

I would like to determine which methods are used alot, a little or not at all by users categorized by their device, os, etc.

Is there a grade plug in to do this out of the box?

Or what keywords are associated with this particular task?

Comment: Used by user's, and not by static code before compilation?  That isn't the realm of a gradle plugin, that's analytics.

Comment: Gotcha thanks..just measure when method is called, like any other analytic call.  Your comment is suitable as an answer